How to JSON formatted big data send to GEMINI to ask for analysis?
import pathlib
import json
import textwrap

import google.generativeai as genai

from IPython.display import display
from IPython.display import Markdown


def to_markdown(text):
  text = text.replace('•', '  *')
  return Markdown(textwrap.indent(text, '> ', predicate=lambda _: True))

from google.colab import userdata

GOOGLE_API_KEY='xxxxxxx'

genai.configure(api_key=GOOGLE_API_KEY)

json_file_path = pathlib.Path("/content/sample_data/BigData.json")
with open(json_file_path, "r") as f:
    json_data = json.load(f)

prompt = "can you report analysis of this json data?"

data = {
    "prompt": prompt,
    "data": json_data
}

print("data= ", data)

model = genai.GenerativeModel('gemini-pro')

chat = model.start_chat(history=[])

response = chat.send_message(json.dumps(data))


to_markdown(response.text)

ERROR:tornado.access:500 POST /v1beta/models/gemini-pro:generateContent?%24alt=json%3Benum-encoding%3Dint (127.0.0.1) 3329.36ms
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InternalServerError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-8b84417dca32> in <cell line: 40>()
     38 chat = model.start_chat(history=[])
     39 
---> 40 response = chat.send_message(json.dumps(data))
     41 
     42 

8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/google/ai/generativelanguage_v1beta/services/generative_service/transports/rest.py in __call__(self, request, retry, timeout, metadata)
    854             # subclass.
    855             if response.status_code >= 400:
--> 856                 raise core_exceptions.from_http_response(response)
    857 
    858             # Return the response

InternalServerError: 500 POST https://generativelanguage.googleapis.com/v1beta/models/gemini-pro:generateContent?%24alt=json%3Benum-encoding%3Dint: An internal error has occurred. Please retry or report in https://developers.generativeai.google/guide/troubleshooting

This code is run for small size JSON files. However big data json files this error occurs!
How can I solve this problem? Could you pls handle the right code?

remember InternalServerError can also be something on their end.

Its actually easer then that.   See not below about sending only string data.
# Print the contents of the file
response = chat.send_message(f"{prompt} \n {json_string_data }")

You just add the json data inline to your prompt.  Its exactly what Ai Studio does.  This can be done with all text data really.  I have tried with text, and pdf.
PRO TIP: With json it can be a little tricky it may get upset if there is any strange chars in your text.  you may need to do some clean up on it remember this is still a beta tool.
If i recall i did a utf-8 and it helped with Json.
# Open the file in read mode with specified encoding
with open('filename.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    # Read the entire contents of the file
    file_contents = file.read()

Let me know if you find any chars it doesn't like and i will report them to the team.
Note string vs object:
file.read() reads the contents of a file as a string, without any parsing or conversion. Using file.read() will give you a string representation of that JSON data.  json.load() not only reads the file but also parses the JSON data within it, providing you with a Python object.
You dont want to send an object to gemini you only want to send a string prompt.
Sample without chat
# Open the file in read mode with specified encoding
with open('testData//test.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    # Read the entire contents of the file
    json_data = file.read()
print(f"Json Data Loaded from file: {json_data}")
response = model.generate_content(f"What is the users name? {json_data}")
print(response.text)

Sample with chat
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import google.generativeai as genai
import os

load_dotenv()
genai.configure(api_key=os.getenv("API_KEY"))
CHAT_MODEL_NAME = "gemini-pro"
model = genai.GenerativeModel(model_name=CHAT_MODEL_NAME)

# Open the file in read mode with specified encoding
with open('testData//test.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    # Read the entire contents of the file
    json_data = file.read()

convo = model.start_chat(history=[])

prompt = f"What is the users name? {json_data}"
# send message with the new request from the user.
convo.send_message(prompt)

print(convo.last.text)


ERROR:tornado.access:500 POST /v1beta/models/gemini-pro:generateContent?%24alt=json%3Benum-encoding%3Dint (127.0.0.1) 2717.84ms
InternalServerError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 50>()
48
49 # Print the contents of the file
---> 50 response = chat.send_message(f"{prompt} \n {json_data }")
51
52
error occured again. my code runs small sized json. but big data eroor occured

dont do json load just load it as text file_contents = file.read()

yes bt i tried your code and it didn't run. this error occured again

it failed becouse your code uses  json_data = json.load(f) mine uses  file_contents = file.read()

Open the file in read mode with specified encoding
with open('testData//test.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
# Read the entire contents of the file
json_data = file.read()
print(f"Json Data Loaded from file: {json_data}")
response = model.generate_content(f"What is the users name? {json_data}")
print(response.text)
I Tried this. This runs on small json perfectly as mine. But for big data json files fails.
I think  Gemini has limits on data reception. There should either be a special command for big data or we should send it by another method.

This is the only way to send text with gemini-pro there is no way to send anything larger remember you are limited by the context window for gemini-pro can you upload the same file with AI studio?  Try there.  see if you get the same issue.   gemini  1.5 is designed for larger context windows but you are using 1.0

maybe we should send the json file in pieces in several processes? Can a code be written like this?

it wont matter if your using chat as the entire chat history is sent every time so even if you send it in multiple chat prompts its still in the history
